# Outputting a picture based on a variable's number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, photo

I'm building a "game" where a user clicks on an image and a number is randomly generated. With this number an image is assigned and displayed. Essentially a Rock, Paper, Scissors game. I'm just trying to get the random image to display. However I'm confused as how to go about setting the variable and then displaying it.

Originally I tried creating a variable that inside the switch would be something as follows

```
case 1:
   cpuChoice = <img id="rock" src="rock.jpg" name="rock" width="265" height="250" /> 
   break;
```

And then do a `$("#result").html(cpuChoice);`  (`result` being a `div` id) However I had no luck with that. Further research seemed to suggest I have to store images in a cache, which is what my code currently is set up for. Though I don't believe I'm understanding how to utilize it properly.

The images I'm using are stored in a file with the pages.
Below is an example of my current javascript page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var cpuImage = new Image();
rock.src = 'rock.jpg';
paper.src = 'paper.jpg';
scissors.src = 'scissors.jpg';
lizard.src = 'lizard.jpg';
spock.src = 'spock.jpg';


    $("#paper").click(function(){

        var ranNumberOne = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

    // the switch is for assigning the image based on what number is generated
    switch(ranNumberOne){
        case 1:
            document['rock'].src = rock.jpg;
            break;
        case 2:
            document['paper'].src = paper.jpg;
            break;
        case 3:
            document['scissors'].src = scissors.jpg;
            break;
        case 4:
            document['spock'].src = spock.jpg;
            break;
        case 5:
                document['rock'].src rock.jpg;
            break;

    }
          document.['blank'].src =cpuImage.src;
    });
```

`blank` is just the id of a temporary image I have. the code for it is as follows

```
<img id="blank" src="blank.jpg" name="blank" width="265" height="250" />
```

I've done alert's to make sure my `onclicks` and the random number generator are both working, which they are. It appears that my problem is just getting the image that "the computer picks" to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. A few issues are happening here, all of which are solvable. So...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // You don't need an image object, since you're only
    // determining a string for `src` and applying it to an existing
    // image object
    var cpuImage = "";
    /* Below you're assigning `src` properties to objects that don't exist. */
    rock.src = 'rock.jpg';
    paper.src = 'paper.jpg';
    scissors.src = 'scissors.jpg';
    lizard.src = 'lizard.jpg';
    spock.src = 'spock.jpg';
    /* I see what you're trying to do,
    but try going about it a bit differently, example: */
    var imageBank = {
        'rock' : 'rock.jpg',
        'paper' : 'paper.jpg',
        'scissors' : 'scissors.jpg',
        'lizard' : 'lizard.jpg',
        'spock' : 'spock.jpg'
    };

    $("#paper").click(function(){

    var ranNumberOne = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

    // the switch is for assigning the image based on what number is generated
    switch(ranNumberOne){
        // Assign your 'cpuImage' variable to the associated imageBank key
        case 1:
            cpuImage = imageBank['rock'];
            break;
        case 2:
            cpuImage = imageBank['paper'];
            break;
        case 3:
            cpuImage = imageBank['scissors'];
            break;
        case 4:
            cpuImage = imageBank['lizard'];
            break;
        case 5:
            cpuImage = imageBank['spock'];
            break;

    }
    // Old:
    document.['blank'].src =cpuImage.src;
    // JQuery syntax (assuming you have an image with id `blank`)
    // New:
    $("#blank").attr('src',cpuImage);
});
```

Keep in mind, using things like a `dictionary` AKA `an object as an associative array` (which the `imageBank` variable is) helps to include a bunch more information pertaining to rock, scissors, etc. in one easy-to-maintain place. You can add additional info as well, which will save you time and code in the future.

Hope this helps and best of luck!

Comment: I see now. Essentially I'm creating an array and using the switch to point to the specific value. Thank you very much! I was having a hard time figuring out how to go about it. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In honor of Sheldon Cooper, this  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nQU54/1/) might help.

JS

```
$('.clickme').on('click', function(){
  var randimage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
  $('.putmehere').html('');
  $('.random1').html(randimage);
  $('.holder img#i' + randimage).clone().appendTo('.putmehere');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="blank" src="blank.jpg" name="blank" width="265" height="250" />
</div>
```

js

```
$(function () {
  $("#container")
  .attr("data-name", $("img", this).attr("id"))
  .on("click", function (e) {
   var options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "spock", "blank"];
   var r = (function (n) {
            return options[(n + Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length - n))]
           })(1);
   $("img", this).attr({
            "id": r,
            "name": r,
            "src": r + ".jpg"
   }).parent().attr("data-name", r);
  });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/e3EXs/